# In a subdirectory, how do I delete all files that are 0 bytes in size?

Tags: rm, size

I am used to listing and sorting the size of files as follows:

```
$ for entry in $(ls); do du -s "$entry"; done | sort -n
```

However, how does one delete all files of 0 bytes?

My terrible attempt would be to try an if conditional, but I don't know how to check the size. I would then pipe all results and remove these?

```
$ for entry in $(ls); if du -s "$entry" == 0 | rm "$entry"
```

Comment: [You shouldn't iterate over ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: [don't parse the output of `ls`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size 0 -delete
```

Comment: `find * -prune -type f -size 0 -exec rm {} \;` if you don't have `-maxdepth`

Comment: @don_crissti One! (Comment edited) It was on a BSD system

Comment: Updated my answer to add `-type f`, thanks @Fox

Comment: Just FYI, I don't think maxdepth works with OS X

Comment: @ShanZhengYang I don't know about newer OS X, but it works in 10.4.11